# Create predicate with nested classes with Expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression, predicate

I have this :

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }
}
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like a some case generate the predicate like this :

```
var result = listPerson.Where(x => x.Age == 10).ToList<>();
```

Or this :

```
var result  = listPerson.Where( x => x.Company.Name == 1234).ToList();
```

Or this :

```
var result  = listPerson.Where( x => x.City.ZipCode == "MyZipCode").ToList();
```

Or this :

```
var result  = listPerson.Where( x => x.Company.Name == "MyCompanyName").ToList();
```

Then I created a "PredicateBuilder", that's work (I get the type, if nullable or not and I build the predicate) when I do this :

```
BuildPredicate<Person>("Age", 10); I get this : x => x.Age == 10
```

But I don't how manage when there is an nested property like this :

```
BuildPredicate<Person>("City.ZipCode", "MyZipCode"); 
I'd like get this : x => x.City.ZipCode == "MyZipCode"
```

Or this :

```
BuildPredicate<Person>("City.Name", "MyName"); 
I'd like get this : x => x.City.Name == "MyName"
```

Or this :

```
BuildPredicate<Person>("Company.Name", "MyCompanyName"); 
I'd like get this : x => x.Company.Name == "MyCompanyName"
```

Comment: Are you completely sure you need to provide your property names like strings? Generally, that is bad idea.

Comment: Please post existing code of BuildPredicate

Comment: @AgentFire you are right, I'm open to change but there is UnitTest, then in case of typo ... but first I need to solve problem

Comment: It's not about solving the issue. It's about self-perfection. It is good thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(not intending to duplicate Jon - OP contacted me to provide an answer)

The following seems to work fine:

```
static Expression<Func<T,bool>> BuildPredicate<T>(string member, object value) {
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Expression body = p;
    foreach (var subMember in member.Split('.')) {
        body = Expression.PropertyOrField(body, subMember);
    }
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(
        body, Expression.Constant(value, body.Type)), p);
}
```

The only functional difference between that and Jon's answer is that it handles `null` *slightly* better, by telling `Expression.Constant` what the expected type is. As a demonstration of usage:

```
static void Main() {
    var pred = BuildPredicate<Person>("City.Name", "MyCity");

    var people = new[] {
        new Person { City = new City { Name = "Somewhere Else"} },
        new Person { City = new City { Name = "MyCity"} },
    };
    var person = people.AsQueryable().Single(pred);
}
```

Comment: Why your code (you and Jon) is all the time more simple than mine :)

Comment: I implemented >, >=, < and <= when I the field is (int, decimal, ....) but I don't see how to implement "StartsWith" and "Contains"

Comment: @Kris-I are we still having the same conversation? 'cos I think you jumped some context there.

Comment: Yes and no. I use you BuilderPredicate and a I added a second one receiving in parameter a "TypeComparator", it's almost the same of yours but some code is different. This part "Expression.Equal(
        body, Expression.Constant(value, body.Type))" change depending of the comparator. I'd like to the same for "StartsWith", "Contains"

Comment: @Kris-I I'll give you a hint: it involves something like `Expression.Call(body, "StartsWith", null, targetVal)`

Comment: If the object is a string, how can you make the property value to be compared lower case without causing trouble for boolean, integer etc?

Comment: The same goes for `datetime` where you perhaps want to compare date only, not time.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to split your expression by dots, and then iterate over it, using `Expression.Property` multiple times. Something like this:

```
string[] properties = path.Split('.');
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
var lhs = parameter;
foreach (var property in properties)
{
    lhs = Expression.Property(lhs, property);
}
// I've assumed that the target is a string, given the question. If that's
// not the case, look at Marc's answer.
var rhs  = Expression.Constant(targetValue, typeof(string));
var predicate = Expression.Equals(lhs, rhs);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(predicate, parameter);
```

Comment: very minor feedback: `Expression.Parameter` requires a *type*, and it is worth providing a type to `Expression.Constant`, so that it can handle `null` correctly. The `Exoression.Parameter` snafu immediately tells me this is "notepad/markdown" code, though - so: close enough!

Comment: @Kris-I the `path.Split` and `foreach` handles arbitrary levels

Comment: @MarcGravell: Oh completely. Will fix up.