# How to do dynamic comparison in Linq to SQL with a string field?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

How to do dynamic comparison in Linq to SQL with a string field for obtain a query like:

```
"SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2" +
"FROM "+ stringTABLE +
"WHERE " + stringCOLUMN_1_or2  + " = ' " + 8 + "'";
```

I know that i can this:

```
from x in objects
where x.COLUMN_1 == "8"
select x
```

but the FIELD is variable, can be COLUMN_1 or COLUMN_2" or other...

as an example of what I want to do in Windows Forms (framework 4.0)

```
from x in objets
where x.field[stringCOLUMN_1_or2] == "8"
select x
```

how I can do this?
thanks in advance

Comment: it seems that you want the `linq to sql dynamic` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697345/linq-to-sql-need-dynamic-where-clause-over-relational-tables-help

Comment: `where x.field[stringCOLUMN_1] == " 8"` -- but I'm not entirely sure I follow your question

Comment: Note: `...COLUMN_2" + "FROM...` yields an invalid query.  (also `...stringTABLE + "WHERE ...` unless stringTABLE ends with a `' '`.

Comment: I wish to do something like to dynamic comparation but without much code

Comment: How do you know which column to use for the comparison?

Comment: the name the field (column) i get from a combobox to filter data

Answer (score 3):

Normally, LINQ to SQL will create a property that is named the same as your column, so your LINQ would likely look like this:

```
from x in objets
where x.stringCOLUMN_1 == 8.ToString()
select x;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be `x.COLUMN_1`?  (Linq wouldn't know what variables he used to create a query...)

Comment: I'm just going off the actual SQL query provided.  It's not entirely clear what the name of the column is in SQL server.

Comment: the FIELD is variable, can be COLUMN_1 or COLUMN_2" or other... stringCOLUMN is string variable that contain the name the column

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what objects is, or your field collection, but first you should have quotes around the literal if it is a string comparison:

```
from x in objets
where x.field[stringCOLUMN_1] == "8"
select x
```

Usually your column names are represented as properties.

```
from x in objets
where x.stringCOLUMN_1 == "8"
select x
```

Lastly, usually you have a DBContext and you need to drill into it to select a specific table:

```
from x in db.TableNameHere
where x.stringCOLUMN_1 == "8"
select x
```

Without seeing more context to your code it's hard to provide more suggestions.

If you're looking to do something more dynamic, note you can append additional where criteria using extension methods:

```
var query = from x in db.TableNameHere select x;
if(ShouldFilterColumn1)
  query = query.Where(x => x.Column1 == "8");

var results = query.ToList();
```

Without seeing more context to your code it's hard to provide more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `ExpressionTree`

[How to: Use Expression Trees to Build Dynamic Queries (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882637.aspx)

[Create predicate with nested classes with Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258881/create-predicate-with-nested-classes-with-expression), where [Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14267890/1600051) looks simple and workable.

**Update:**
Link from above are not help in case of LinqToSql.

Look at Trisped answer (second option), it may help.

Comment: I'm currently testing Marc Gravell's answer in .net 4.0.  Any chance it's not working anymore, or he was expecting .net 4.5?  (`Where()` wants a `Func<>` instead of `Expression<>` on my system)

Comment: I'm sorry a lot, it wouldn't help. These samples are for Linq To Entities.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use reflection:

```
from x in db.TableName
    where (x.GetType().GetProperty(stringCOLUMN_1_or2).GetValue(x, null)) == " 8"
    select x;
```

Not sure there's any easy Linqish way to do that though...

EDIT: Assuming dynamic Linq will work it would just be:

```
from x in objets
.Where(stringCOLUMN_1_or2  + " = ' " + 8 + "'")
select x
```

There is some more info about dynamic Linq with SQL here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: How it would be translated in SQL script?

Comment: @AlexanderBalte Wouldn't that be up to the Linq to SQL engine?  I guess it would depend on whether x's properties were place-holders or data values in a temp object.

Comment: You can't you reflection in LinqToSql statement. Even `String.IsNullOrEmpty`.

Comment: @AlexanderBalte ok, so this only works for Linq, not Linq to SQL.

Comment: in x.GetType().GetProperty("COLUMN_2") is null... with this can´t do the compare

Comment: @ch2o that sounds like you need to match the actual property names with your objects?  It may be misnamed or it may be a member instead of a property.  (Note: I'm told this won't work with Linq to SQL though)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three possibilities.

The first is dynamic LINQ.  I looked into this once but did not get very far.

The second option (similar to the suggestion by AaronLS) is to build the queries one step at a time.  This is the option I use most often.
**Note**: You must add the where clauses before the select or order clauses or you will get an exception at run time.

```
var query = from x in objects;
switch (columnIndicator)
{
    case ColumnIndicatorTypes.Column1:
        query = query.Where(x => x.Column1 == "8");
        break;
    case ColumnIndicatorTypes.Column2:
        query = query.Where(x => x.Column2 == "8");
        break;
    case ColumnIndicatorTypes.Column3:
        query = query.Where(x => x.Column3 == "8");
        break;
    case ColumnIndicatorTypes.Column4:
        query = query.Where(x => x.Column4 == "8");
        break;
}
```

The third option is to code all the options.  For example:

```
switch (columnIndicator)
{
    case ColumnIndicatorTypes.Column1:
        query = from x in objects
            where x.COLUMN_1 == "8"
            select x;
        break;
    case ColumnIndicatorTypes.Column2:
        query = from x in objects
            where x.COLUMN_2 == "8"
            select x;
        break;
    case ColumnIndicatorTypes.Column3:
        query = from x in objects
            where x.COLUMN_3 == "8"
            select x;
        break;
    case ColumnIndicatorTypes.Column4:
        query = from x in objects
            where x.COLUMN_4 == "8"
            select x;
        break;
    default:
        query = from x in objects
            select x;
        break;
}
```

If you want to see the query generated I suggest either hooking up to `db.Log` before running the query (something like `db.Log = New System.IO.StringWriter(New StringBuilder())`), run a profiler on your server (like SQL Server Profiler), or cast the object to a string (I think this returns the string version of the query, but it has been a while).